# Angular web app shows web page even if no angular process is running

Tags: node.js, angular

I have the following issue with an angular based application:

for instance, I perform the following

1. In a browser, an angular based application is opened -  eg http://test.com/default
2. Then The angular process is terminated manually
3. After the angular is terminated, the page from step 1 is still available/displayed until I refresh it.

So, the question is

Is there any **way to not display the page automatically** if the angular process has died.

I can force to reload the page, say every 5 minutes through the **location.reload(**), but I don't like this approach

```
  ngOnInit() {
        // Some code Here

        // Refresh the component every 1 minute
        this.PageReload();
  }

  PageReload() {
    let refreshInterval = interval(60000);
    refreshInterval.subscribe(n => location.reload());
  }
```

Comment: this is really a bad idea to reload the page every 1 min, if you are in the middle of a process, the page will reload and ```tadaa``` you are finished.

Comment: The application is a simple dashboard page. So no data loss. But anyway as I said I don't like this approach.

Comment: this is the default behaviour of the browser, take this example, you are browsing a website - webpage loads and suddenly your network goes down. Still, you are viewing the page, until you reload it. this is what happens in this case.

Comment: @Akhil, hm.. you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a SPA(single page Application) which renders the page only once while you hit the server **(in your case http://test.com/default or when you reload the App)**.

You will get error message when you hit any API while the Angular is not running. Based on that message you can take actions like redirecting to an error page for display.

Hope this helps.